# Can't apply migrations in Django project

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm creatig a custom user model, inherit it from AbstractUser. When i'm making migrations i got ValueError('Related model %r cannot be resolved' % self.remote_field.model)
ValueError: Related model 'reviews.user' cannot be resolved

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

# Пользовательские роли.
ROLES = [
    ('user', 'Пользователь'),
    ('moderator', 'Модератор'),
    ('admin', 'Администратор'),
]

class User(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(
        max_length=150,
        unique=True,
    )
    email = models.EmailField(
        max_length=254,
        unique=True,
        blank=False,
    )
    first_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=150,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    last_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=150,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    bio = models.TextField(
        verbose_name='Биография',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    role = models.CharField(
        max_length=256,
        verbose_name='Роль',
        choices=ROLES,
        default='user',
    )
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Пользователь',
        verbose_name_plural = 'Пользователи'
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

class Title(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        'Название',
        max_length=256,
    )
    year = models.IntegerField('Год выпуска')
    description = models.TextField('Описание')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'объект "Произведение"'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Произведения'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

settings

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'reviews.User'
```

I can't understand what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think you must check your file directory.

or

Check if the review has been properly registered.

The information you posted last may not be enough to determine the cause. It would be nice if you could post it in as much detail as possible.